# Some info missing on Drupal 7 ckeditor accordion instructions

Tags: views, nodes

Trying go to get this working:

https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_accordion

But it's not working, step 5 and 6 don't exist or I can't find them in Drupal 7, are these instructions for Drupal 8 only?

```
 5.Scroll down to the bottom to the input Allowed HTML tags
 6.Find and replace <dl> with <dl class>
```

Can't find 5 and 6 in the backend

Comment: If the module's own documentation page is (maybe) wrong, you should file a support request for documentation in the module's issue queue instead of asking here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on drupal.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to */admin/config/content/formats* and click configure on the format that you'll be using.

[image]

Scroll all the way down and click on "Limit allowed HTML tags" tab. Now replace `<dl>` with `<dl class>`

[image]